# Algorithm for generating a random grid for materialUI with rows that add up to 3 columns

Tags: javascript, material-ui

I am building a React application working with the reddit api and oAuth.

I am using MaterialUI, and I am attempting to use the  Component to construct a 3 column grid of images that have dynamically generated column width values, max obviously being 3.

The first item in the array of fetched image posts will be given a key/value pair of a random number between 1 and 3. The second item will be given a key/value pair of a number completing the row, if the first item's value is != 3.

Then, it will start over again, the idea being that every time the grid loads, its first item might be 1 column wide, 2 columns wide, or the whole row of 3 columns wide, and the algorithm is supposed to complete the rest of the grid accordingly, meaning the rows all must add up to 3.

I have tried processing the array of posts in numerous ways, from assigning values to the first two objects in the array outside of a loop, then defining a 'last post' and 'post before that' variable to try to figure out a way to make the rows add up. I've tried to come up with a set of rules that would make this work regardless of array position, but cannot seem to come to an answer that doesn't have a few edge cases.

```
makeTiles() {
    let posts = this.props.posts;
    let postsWithCols = [];
    posts[0].cols = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3 + 1);
    console.log(posts[0])
    postsWithCols.push(posts[0]);
    let previousPost = postsWithCols[postsWithCols.length - 1];
    switch(previousPost.cols) {
      case 1: 
      console.log('is1');
      posts[1].cols = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2 + 1);
      postsWithCols.push(posts[1]);
      break;
      case 2: 
      console.log('is2');
      posts[1].cols = 1;
      postsWithCols.push(posts[1]);
      break;
      case 3: 
      console.log('is3');
      posts[1].cols = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3 + 1);
      postsWithCols.push(posts[1]);
      break;
      default:
      console.log('something went wrong');
      break;
    }
    let postBeforeThat = postsWithCols[postsWithCols.length - 2];
    console.log(previousPost)
    console.log(postBeforeThat)
    console.log(postsWithCols)
  }
  render() {
    this.makeTiles();
    return (
      <div>
        open grid when i can get tileData figured out.
        {/* <ImageGrid tileData={this.makeTiles()} {...this.props}/> */}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The only way I have ever had this kind of work, it kept alternating between 1 and 2 after the first initial tile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to come to this as a solution eventually.

```
      getPostsWithColumns = (posts) => {
    const postsWithColumns = posts.reduce((accum, post) => {
      const lastIndex = accum.length - 1;
      if (accum[lastIndex] && this.totalColumns(accum[lastIndex]) < 3) {
        const currentTotal = this.totalColumns(accum[lastIndex]);
        const postWithCols = {
          ...post,
          cols: currentTotal === 2 ? 1 : this.randomNumber(2)
        };
        accum[lastIndex] = [...accum[lastIndex], postWithCols];
        return accum;
      }
      const postWithCols = {
        ...post,
        cols: this.randomNumber(3)
      }
      return [...accum, [postWithCols]];
    }, []);
    return postsWithColumns.reduce((accum, group) => [...accum, ...group], []);
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of issues here. First of all, the code as presented really only will give you two post column values max. There is nothing looping or going back to fill in more columns. Second, I think what you are trying to do it have it create an array of posts that also have column values but the method never returns the final value (`postsWithCols`). I am going to assume you still just want a list of posts with column values and to not have it further split up in to rows.

```
let posts = this.props.posts;

// Const for the max
const maxColumns = 3;

// Variable to keep track of current remaining columns. 
let remainingColumns = maxColumns;

// Go over each post and return the post with cols in to a new array. 
let postsWithCols = posts.map((post, index) => {
   // Special case, if last item, fill remaining
   if (index === posts.length - 1) {
      post.cols = remainingColumns;
      return post;
   }

   // Get a random number for the remaining columns for this row
   const cols = Math.floor(Math.random() * remainingColumns + 1);
   post.cols = cols;

   // Subtract the value
   remainingColumns = remainingColumns - cols;

   // If value is 0, reset to max. 
   if (remainingColumns <= 0) {
      remainingColumns = maxColumns;
   }

   // Add to result array
   return post;
});

console.log(postsWithCols);
```

There is more that could be tweaked about this, but this is the general idea.

Comment: im going to work on this and get back to you tomorrow! Thank you so much for helping out!